# Porque meu jquery está duplicando as linhas da tabela?

Tags: jquery, tabela-html, paginação

Estou fazendo uma tabela paginada (com 3 linhas por página), porém ao adicionar as linhas na tabela o jquery está duplicando isso.

Ao clicar nos ícones de mudar de página ele adiciona mais itens e embaixo desses itens aparece o que deveria aparecer (ou seja apenas 3 itens).

O que poderia ser? Como posso resolver? O que estou fazendo de errado?
Agradeço desde já os comentários!!!

Segue código abaixo:

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
var storage = [
  ['Banana', '10,00'],
  ['Maça', '2,00'],
  ['Pera', '6,00'],
  ['Goiaba', '3,25'],
  ['Tamarindo', '1,50'],
  ['Cenoura', '0,75'],
  ['Alface', '0,99'],
  ['Tomate', '3,21'],
  ['Abacaxi', 'N/D'],
  ['Kiwi', '99,50'],
  ['Cebola', '1,15'],
  ['Alho', '1,02'],
  ['Abóbora', '4,75'],
  ['Pêssego', '2,33'],
  ['Laranja', '2,99']
];

var page = 0;
var maxRow = 3;

function createDash()
{
    $('.pagination > tr').remove();
    
    for 
    (
    var i = page * maxRow; 
          i < storage.length && 
          i < (page + 1) *  maxRow; 
          i++
    )
    {
        $('tbody').append(
            '<tr>'+
              '<td>'+ storage[i][0] +'</td>'+
                '<td>'+ storage[i][1] +'</td>'+
            '</tr>'
        );          
    }
    $('.pages').text('Page '+ (page + 1) +' of '+ Math.ceil(storage.length / maxRow));
}

$('.fa-chevron-right').click((e)=>
{
    e.preventDefault();
    
    if (page < storage.length / maxRow && page <= maxRow)
    {
        page++;
        createDash();
    } else {}
    
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
    
$('.fa-chevron-left').click((e)=>
{
    e.preventDefault();
    
    if (page > 0) 
    {
        page --;
        createDash();
    } else {}
    
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
    
createDash();
});
```

```css
* {
    font-family: 'Arial';
}

table {
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: #0ff090;
}

td, tr, tbody, th {
    padding: 15px 0;
    text-align: center;
}

tr td {
    width: 50%;
}

label {
    padding: 0 30px
}

.header {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px 0;
    background: #131417;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgb(0 0 0 / 20%);
}

.header i {
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 50px;
    transition: .2s ease-out;
}

.header i:hover {
    color: #131417;
    background: #0ff090;
}

.pagination {
    background: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>

<table>
    <div class="header">
        <i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i>
        <label class="pages">TABLE</label>
        <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
    </r>
    <tr>
        <td>FOOD</td>
        <td>PRICE</td>
    </tr>
    <tbody class="pagination">
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi alterando o append de $('tbody') para $('.pagination') que seria a classe do tbody.
Deve ter ocorrido conflito entre o html, talvez a  ja tenha por padrao o tbody.